# Python: get int value from a char string

Tags: python, char, chr, ord

This is one of those silly questions and I don't really know how to formulate it, so I'll give an example. I got

```
v = chr(0xae) + chr(0xae)
```

where #AEAE is, in decimal, the value of 44718.

My question is how I get the integer value of `v`? I know about `ord()` but I can use it only for a char, and not for a string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this using the `struct` module:

```
import struct
int_no = struct.unpack('>H', v)[0]
print int_no
```

which outputs the desired results:

```
44718
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an arbitrary-length string of bytes to an `int` or `long` using one of these expressions.

```
i = reduce(lambda x, y: (x<<8)+ord(y), v, 0)
i = reduce(lambda x, y: (x<<8)+ord(y), reversed(v), 0)
```

Use the one of them for little-endian data and the other for big-endian data. Or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to convert a hexadecimal to an integer rather than a char string.

```
>>> int("AEAE",16)
44718
```

or

```
>>> int("0xAEAE",16)
44718
```

In reply to your comment, one way I can think of would be to use bitshifts:

```
>>> (ord('\xae') << 8) | (ord('\xae'))
44718
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way though.

Comment: The issue is that I get this data from a remote server, which is represented as `'\xae\xae'`, so this is what I need to convert to `int()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the straightforward way would be to go:

```
def convert(v):
    x = 0
    for c in v:
        x *= 256
        x += ord(c)
    return x
```

If you want to have the leftmost character to have the largest value.

You can reverse `v` beforehand to get the opposite endian-ness.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to keep the hex as a string and use `int()`:

```
int("AEAE", 16)
```